# Google Address Suggestions country restrictions does not working properly

Tags: google-maps, street-address

To add country restrictions for google address suggestions, we can just add

```
autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({"country":["US"]}); //Display US address only

autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({"country":["US","CA"]}); //Display US, CA only
```

**It's working fine as expected**. But If I add more countries like below then I don't see addresses for few countries US, UK, FR etc:

```
autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({"country":["AU","AT","BE","CA","CN","CY","EE","FI","FR","DE","GR","HK","IE","IT","JP","LV","LT","LU","MT","MC","NL","PT","SK","SI","ES","GB","US"]});
```

**Debugging Result:**

I found after CN countries not getting restricted. So I thought may be Issue with incorrect country code. But all codes are correct.

I thought may be issue with country code CY (Cyprus).
But If I use. It's working.

autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({"country":["CY"]}); //Display CY address only

Not getting what is the issue. Anyone faced Issue like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only provide a maximum of five country codes.  See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#ComponentRestrictions):

> Restricts predictions to the specified country (ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 country code, case insensitive). For example, 'us', 'br', or 'au'. **You can provide a single one, or an array of up to five country code strings.**

Comment: If I don't give any restrictions I see all countries addresses. If need to get addresses for specific countries  it's limited to 5. Not sure why they did that. Anyway Is there any option I can see addresses for more then 5 selected  countries?